# Calling Python or exeternal functions from Solidity smart contracts

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to call some existing python code (code that uses a neural network for object classification) with a solidity smart contract.
On the front-end there has to be an image-input, then the classification gives the result true or false. This bool must be then stored in the smart contract.
If a user accesses the  "classify-function" in the smart contract, the classifier must be initiated for file-upload. After the file-upload the classification (in python) has to be done, the result must be stored as a smart-contract variable onchain.
Is it possible to call a python function with a solidity function?
And if yes, any hints or code snippets?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call Python function, or any function, with Solidity, because this is not how blockchains work. You are limited to execution within the EVM environment.

[Please read details in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63004386/315168).